# Knockout.js Function Return Value in Foreach?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, foreach

I'm trying to use Knockout JS to render nested foreach values.

What I'm looking to do is get the distinct values of each grouped parameter.

HTML:

```
<!-- ko if: documentVM.Groups().length != 0 -->
<tbody data-bind="foreach: documentVM.Groups">
    <!-- ko foreach: documentVM.sortGroup(val)  -->
        <tr class="groupHead">
            <td colspan="5" data-bind="text: val"></td>
        </tr>
    <!-- /ko -->
</tbody>
<!-- /ko -->
```

JS:

```
self.sortGroup = function(groupby) {
    return ko.computed(function() {
        var groupkey = ko.utils.arrayMap(self.filteredRecords(), function(item) { return item[groupby]; });
        var computed = ko.utils.arrayGetDistinctValues(groupkey);
        return computed;
        });
    };
```

Unfortunately, this code blows up, even though computed is an array of distinct values as expected.

Is there a different way to go about this that would work better?

Comment: Can you post full HTML and JS. Its not super clear how to answer.

Comment: Do you have to return the computed function? Why not make it a function without using the computed?

Comment: What's `val` in your inner `foreach` binding (as opposed to `val` in your `text` binding)?